# Hotkey X = Delete AND X axis?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, hotkeys

I am using Mojave with Blender 2.8 downloaded in September. 
My question is about the Hotkey X. When I want to delete, I type X and the little window is confirming if I want to delete and all is well. But when I want to move my object on the X axis, I also type X. For a second it will move my object on the X axis, but then the little Delete window appears and before I can do anything, my object is deleted. How can there be one hotkey for two different actions?
I assume that I can change that in Preference  > Keymap, but which should I change, and to what?
Thanks for any help. 
Marie H

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think I got it: to Delete I first type X and the little Delete window shows up. To move along the X axis, I first position my pointer on the Red arrow when the Move gizmo is selected, and ONLY THEN do I type X. The Delete window doesn't show up and the object moves along the X axis. I just figured it out by noodling with my pen an tablet. If there is a better way, please let me know.